# How to send messages to the dead letter queue in Azure Service Bus using MassTransit?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, masstransit

I'm new to Azure Service Bus and MassTransit. Now I'm experimenting with messages and I want to send a Message that goes into the Dead Letter Queue of the Azure Service Bus. What should such a message look like? Will it only appear in the Dead Letter Queue if there is no consumer? And how should I consume a Dead Letter Message by creating a dead letter consumer?

Thanks in advance :)

Consumer:

```
         public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IEventCreated> context)
         {
            try
            {
                var serializedMessage = JsonSerializer.Serialize(context.Message, new JsonSerializerOptions());
                logger.LogInformation("Event consumed: {serializedMessage}", serializedMessage);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogError(ex, "Error while processing message {messageId}. Retry attempt {retryAttempt}", context.MessageId, context.GetRetryAttempt());
                throw;
            }
        }
```

My consumer definition:

```
public class EventCreatedConsumerDefinition : ConsumerDefinition<EventCreatedConsumer>
    {
        protected override void ConfigureConsumer(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator,IConsumerConfigurator<EventCreatedConsumer> consumerConfigurator)
        {
            endpointConfigurator.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Interval(5, 500));
            endpointConfigurator.ConfigureDeadLetterQueueDeadLetterTransport();
            endpointConfigurator.ConfigureDeadLetterQueueErrorTransport();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When configured to use the dead-letter queue (DLQ), MassTransit will move faulted or skipped messages to the DLQ instead of creating separate *_error* or *_skipped* queues.

If a message consumer throws an exception, and all retry/redelivery limits are reached, the message is dead-lettered using the Azure SDK along with additional message headers detailing the reason/exceptions that occurred.

As for how to deal with messages in the DLQ, you can use Azure Service Bus Explorer (in the Azure Portal) or the old client Windows application to examine/move the messages, or consider other options like a SaaS service that can monitor/move those messages for you.

> [Message Aid](https://https://messageaid.com/) is an early stage tool that does this, author is the co-founder of MassTransit.